# Cómo hago que un textarea me capture los datos de un select y los sume?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Necesito que un `textarea` me valla sumando los datos seleccionados en un `select`. Hasta el momento me muestra el dato seleccionado en el `textarea,`pero al seleccionar otra opción, no me mantiene el `select` anterior en el `textarea`. Aquí está el código:

```
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
     <script language="javascript">
          function actualizar()
          {
              var miArray=new Array();

              miArray[0]="Ampolleta70";
              miArray[1]="Ampolleta120";
              miArray[2]="Ampolleta1200";

              var texto = document.getElementById('eltexto');

              if(document.getElementById('opcion1').selected) texto.value = miArray[0];
              if(document.getElementById('opcion2').selected) texto.value = miArray[1];
              if(document.getElementById('opcion2').selected) texto.value = miArray[2];
           }
    </Script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
         <select onChange="actualizar()">
             <option id="opcion1">Ampolleta70</option>
             <option id="opcion2">Ampolleta120</option>
             <option id="opcion2">oAmpolleta 1200</option>
         </select>
         <br>
         <textarea id="eltexto" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function actualizar(select){
  var val = select.value;
  document.getElementById('eltexto').value += val;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select onChange="actualizar(this)">
    <option id="opcion1">Ampolleta70</option>
    <option id="opcion2">Ampolleta120</option>
    <option id="opcion2">oAmpolleta 1200</option>
  </select><br>
  <textarea id="eltexto" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
```

No necesitas un arreglo si el `select` ya tiene la información. Ahora, tenías que ir concatenando el valor, no reemplazandolo por uno nuevo, por eso no te funcionaba. Te dejo el ejemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto te puede ayudar un poco

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Documento sin t&iacute;tulo</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <script language="javascript">
        
        var datos = [];

        function actualizar() {

            var select = document.querySelector('#select').value;
            var eltexto = document.querySelector('#eltexto');
            datos.push(select);
            eltexto.value = datos;
        }
    </Script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <select id="select" onChange="actualizar()">
            <option value="Ampolleta70">Ampolleta70</option>
            <option value="Ampolleta120">Ampolleta120</option>
            <option value="Ampolleta1200">oAmpolleta 1200</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <textarea id="eltexto" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Gracias ,Me ayudo mucho ,pero como puedo hacer para borrar el contenido de lo que agregue con el select , si lo borro manualmente y vuelvo a seleccionar por ejemplo la opcion 2 me toma todos los datos anteriores seleccionados nuevamente ,